# Can't subscribe onClick event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap

I have some kind of wizard. I try automatically generate table from json. And I want go to the next step after user clicked on table row. But I can't subscribe on click event. There no event happens. Can I subscribe on row click?

```
    //table element view class
    var ObjectsTableView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'tr',
        id: 'table-item',
        events:{
//no one works
            'click tr' : 'onClick',
            'click th' : 'onClick',
            'click #some' : 'onClick'
        },
        //configure underscore template
        template: _.template('<th id="some"><%= f1 %></th><th><%= f2 %></th><th><%= f3 %></th>'),    
        onClick: function(){
            alert("click");
        },
        render: function(){
            //use template and assign to html
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });
```

ObjectsTableView inserted in DOM at another View. That appears in DOM like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>F1</th>
       <th>F2</th>
       <th>F3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr id="table-item">
       <th id="some">f1</th>
       <th>f2</th>
       <th>f3</th>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

But clicking on table row not throw event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem lies in how you're using `id` and `tagName`. When you specify [`id`, `tagName`, `className`, or `attributes` properties](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-el):

> `this.el` is created from the view's `tagName`, `className`, `id` and `attributes` properties, if specified. If not, `el` is an empty `div`.

So Backbone will create `<tr id="table-item"></tr>` is your `this.el` in the view but you're not inserting that into the DOM anywhere. You'd need to do something like:

```
$('table').append(v.render().el);
```

somewhere to get you're view's `el` into the DOM, then you could use just a `click` event with no selector:

```
events: {
    'click': 'onClick'
}
```

Demo (open your console please): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/nLTGv/

If you already have a `<tr id="table-item">` in the DOM then you'd want to use [`el`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-el) in your view definition and, again, a simple selector-less `click` event:

```
var ObjectsTableView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#table-item',
    events: {
        'click': 'onClick'
    },
    //...
```

Then your `this.el` would be the `#table-item` that is already in the DOM.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/7RYBJ/

Comment: It appears in DOM, but clicking does not work. sorry if it was unclear. I add part of DOM in question

Comment: @kiwaa: If it is already in the DOM then you should use `el` in your view, see my second demo.